# Altera FlipFlop stuck at GND

Tags: simulation, flipflop, counter, intel-fpga

I'm trying to make a counter that counts: 0,1,2,3,4,5

I need this for a frequency divider of 6

So I made this table:

[image]

From this I get:

J0= 1

K0= 1

J1 = NOT Q0 AND Q1

K1 = Q1

J2 = Q1 AND Q2

K2 = Q1

I made the circuit in the software:

[image]

It does compile with 1 warning:

[image]

And when simulating only the first jkff is working:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the output of FF 64 is 0. Then the output of AND2 must be 0, no matter the other input value.

Now the J input of FF 64 is 0. With J at 0, the output can never become 1.

Your logic for J1 is not implementing line 2 of your transition table correctly.

Comment: You mean the equation for J1 is not ok?I checked multiple time and it should be ok....

Comment: @FoxAlex, Your transition table says J1 should be 1 for Q[2:0] = 001. Your logic gives an output of 0 for this input.

Comment: You are right, but why?I used this to calculate the equations and also done by hand and it should be good imgur.com/a/utDY3mB
@ThePhoton

Comment: @FoxAlex, I don't know how you mapped Q[2:0] to A, B, and C in the K-map, but it looks like you put a 0 in the 001 location instead of a 1, and you put the 1 in the 010 location.

Comment: You are right, I didn't put the values in the right order in the map, can't believe, I looked at it so many times, thank you.